# If $f(\sin x) = \cos2x$, find $f(\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you even approach this question. Is there something fundamental that i'm missing here.

Comment: What you’re missing is that this is not one equation for $f$, this is a *family* of equations, an infinite number of them — one for each $x$ (for each $x \in [0,2\pi]$ actually, because once you have those, the others don’t say anything new). They determine $f(t)$ for $t \in [-1,1]$ (the range of $\sin$) uniquely. You can solve them for $f$ explicitly, or use tricks like $\sin x = \cos(x-\pi/2)$ or $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ to obtain the answer without doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(\sin(x))=\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
HINT : Change of variable : $\quad X=\sin(x)$
$$f(X)=1-2X^2$$
Now, the function $f$ is known. You can put $\cos(x)$ into it :
$$f(\cos(x))= ...?$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use that $\cos(\alpha-90^\circ)=\sin(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(\sin x) = 1 -2\sin^2x \implies f(x) = 1 - 2x^2 \implies f(\cos x) = 1-....$